# using async/await send email and delete the resource checking condition

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to send email using c# async/await and the program deletes the attached file from computer depending on the flag **"deleteFile"**. Whatever the value of deleteFile flag the email is delivered successfully but when I set deleteFile to true I am getting the following exception. I have to send two separate emails and I need to delete the file only after second mail.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Uploads\TestFile.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

My console application code is:

```
using System;

namespace SendMailAsyncDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string filePath = @"C:\Uploads\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sender mailSender = new Sender();

            mailSender.SendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt", false);

            mailSender.SendEmail("anotheremail@gmail.com.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt", true);

            Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!!!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Sender class to send email:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SendMailAsyncDemo
{
    public class Sender
    {
        public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath, bool deleteFile = false)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                SendEmailAsync(toEmail, title, body, attachmentPath, deleteFile);
            });
        }

        private async void SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath, bool deleteFile)
        {
            Attachment attachment = null;

            try
            {
                // class to hold all values from the section system.net/mailSettings/smtp in app.config
                MailConfiguration smtpSection = new MailConfiguration();

                using (MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("<" + smtpSection.FromAddress + ">", toEmail))
                {
                    mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailMsg.Subject = title;
                    mailMsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    mailMsg.Body = body;
                    mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath) && File.Exists(attachmentPath))
                    {
                        attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                        mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }

                    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtpClient.Timeout = 1000000;
                        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                        if (deleteFile)
                        {
                            smtpClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                attachment.Dispose();
                                File.Delete(attachmentPath);
                            };
                        }
                        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg);                       
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SendEmail exception: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("SendEmail done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're using `SendMailAsync` you don't have to use the older `SendCompleted` event - you're already handed back a `Task` that tells you when it's complete, and you're already making use of that with an `await`. I'd move the delete action below all of the `using`s in case one of those objects is the "other" process.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated my question because I need to send two emails and need to delete the file only after the second email is sent. Is Is that possible?

Comment: Sidenote: `private async void SendEmailAsync` - It is recommended to make this `private async Task SendEmailAsync`

Comment: What I'd try to do is pass along a state object which has a "FilesToDelete" List. If the marker is true, then I'd add the File to that list. In the caller I'd then use WhenAll to wait for all Send operations to finish and give it a continuation with a task that dleetes all files in the list ... something along that.

Comment: You've currently designed yourself into a corner - you have no way of knowing whether the first `SendEmailAsync` or the second will *finish last* and so no way of knowing after which of them it is safe to perform a delete. I'd take out the explicit threading, expose `async`/`await` up the stack, use `Task` rather than `void` and, *at a point in the program which knows about both emails*, have some form of `WaitAll`/`WhenAll` on the tasks representing both emails, after which a delete is known to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there's no simple way to fix this while maintaining this same program structure. In particular, since you've currently got two ongoing email send calls with no knowledge of each other, there's no way to determine *when* it's safe to perform the delete. The second `Send` could finish first.

Changes I would make - I'd delete `SendEmail` and make `SendEmailAsync` `public` and `Task` returning. I'd also remove the concept of deleting after:

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // class to hold all values from the section system.net/mailSettings/smtp in app.config
            MailConfiguration smtpSection = new MailConfiguration();

            using (MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("<" + smtpSection.FromAddress + ">", toEmail))
            {
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMsg.Subject = title;
                mailMsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mailMsg.Body = body;
                mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath) && File.Exists(attachmentPath))
                {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }

                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtpClient.Timeout = 1000000;
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg);                       
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendEmail exception: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("SendEmail done");
        }
    }
```

I'd then change `Main` as follows:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sender mailSender = new Sender();

        var send1 = mailSender.SendEmailAsync("myemail@gmail.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt");

        var send2 = mailSender.SendEmailAsync("anotheremail@gmail.com.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt");

        Task.WaitAll(send1,send2);
        File.Delete(filePath + "TestFile.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!!!");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If this wasn't `Main`/if you're using bleeding-edge C#, I'd make it `async` also and use a couple of `await`s at the current point I've got the `WaitAll`. It's the earliest piece of code common to both sends and so the only piece of code that can actually determine *when* it's safe to perform the delete.

Comment: Close to what I thought. Assuming, OP will actually have a dynamic number of mails to send and files to delete, I'd collect file-paths in a Collection - preferably one that automatically excludes duplicates - and then throw that into a continuation ...

Comment: @Fildor - A `Dictionary<string,List<Task>>` or similar?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking wrong ... isn't it possible to go like `Task.WaitAll(....).ContinueWith( ( ListToDelete ) => { ListToDelete.ForEach( file => File.Delete(file); ) } );` ? Or at least something similar?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I really appreciate your time and effort answering my question. The solution that you provided is almost like what I needed but I need to display the message "Email Sent successfully!!!" immediately and all the Tasks could be completed after that. I need to send 100 MB files and it takes a bit long time and I don't want to block my UI.

Comment: @Simant - that's just rearranging a couple of statements in `Main` to achieve. I was also trying to make the system not lie - i.e. not report successful sending unless, you know, we've done everything on our end to be reasonably sure that the emails are sent, but I guess you know your requirements better.